# Hide selected data series and data labels in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY5kJ.jpg)In a Pivotchart, i have data labels with values starting from 0 and they also have name series. How do i show only data labels greater than 3? ( i don’t want my chart to show small values and their series names as it’s really crowded

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can try to provide a sample about the problem.

Comment: I think the problem starts with the phrase "In a PivotChart". Clever custom things will be limited. Consider using a PT to do the heavy lifting and maths, and then mirror this data to a new range using GetPivotData (or just cell references if that works for your scenario). Then chart from the mirrored range and you can do all sorts of conditional stuff using hidden series that have the labels attached, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In the PivotTable dropdown menu there is a Value/Label Filter option where you can set up a Greater Than... condition. If the filter options are all greyed out make sure the data that you want to filter is formatted as number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It’s working for the row/columns total, but not for the values inside the table.

Comment: Unfortunately, i work with senzitive data and can’t show but simpluly put…The Value/Label Filters in the PivotTable filters only the values in the Grand total of Both columns and rows. How can i filter the cell values inside the pivot table?

Comment: @LaviniaMihaela, if you can't show the real data please make a little mock-up Excel file with just enough random data to show the precise problem you are trying to solve. We are guessing now.

Comment: Lavinia, you can filter the cell values inside the pivot table directly if you move whatever the field you are summarizing to the Filters area and unselect the undesirable values (manually).

Beware, that WILL change your Grand Total and might not be what you want.

Another thing, if you change your dataset, you will may have to check again if all values are correctly selected.

Comment: I have added a picture to summarize the situation, basically i want to filter the highlighted numbers inside the PivotTable.